# Simple jquery popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to make a very simple jquery box come up saying "Sorry, that blog post could not be found."

I don't want anything very advanced... How should I go about this?

Comment: I think this question has been done to death, just do a SO search on jQuery popup, facebox, lightbox, etc. and you'll be in business.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out [these nice custom alert and confirmation boxes.](http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook_files/87/demo/) You can customize them.

Comment: Looks like the page has moved to  http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/.  Unfortunately I don't seem to have edit permissions.

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery plug-in **Impromptu** is a good simple choice for a pop-up that looks a lot nicer than a standard JS alert

http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php

There are instructions on the site that will help you in your implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Like the [jQuery UI Dialog?](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/amina)**

```
$('div.no-post').dialog({        
    buttons: { 
        "Ok": function() { 
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
        } 
    },
    title: "Post Not Found",
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false
});

<div class="no-post">
    Sorry, that blog post could not be found.
</div>
```

or I've always liked the [BlockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos)

Comment: It should be noted that if you decided to go this route in addition to vanilla jquery, you'll also need to include the jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css file in order for this to work.  On the plus side you can use the jquery theme roller to make it look exactly like you want.

Comment: @T.Stone- Good point. If you're looking to use a number of UI components in your site then using the UI plugin is probably a good choice. You can specify which plugins to include in the jquery-ui.js, so you don't need to include ones that you're not going to use. Themeroller does make it easy to style the UI plugins too :)